# sql trouble, need to combine 2 runnable code

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 runnable code but i need to combine these 2 codes into 1

```
SELECT `doc`.`date`,`doc`.`no`,`def`.`name`,`i`.`type`
FROM `documents` as `doc` 
    RIGHT JOIN `items` as `i` ON `i`.`document_id` = `doc`.`id` 
    RIGHT JOIN `definitions` as `def` ON `doc`.`type_id` = `def`.`id`
WHERE `doc`.`id`= 2
```

this is the first code that i have

```
SELECT `alacak`,`ödeme`,(`alacak` - `ödeme`) as `bakiye`
FROM (SELECT (SELECT IFNULL(SUM( `quantity` * `price` * `d`.`currency_value` / 100 ), 0) AS `alacak` FROM `items` as `i`
        RIGHT JOIN `documents` as `d` ON `d`.`id` = `i`.`document_id` WHERE `d`.`type_group` = 'sales') as `alacak`,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM( `quantity` * `price` * `d`.`currency_value` / 100 ), 0) AS `ödeme` FROM `items` as `i`
        RIGHT JOIN `documents` as `d` ON `d`.`id` = `i`.`document_id` WHERE `d`.`type_group` = 'purchases') as `ödeme`) as  `table
```

and this is the second

i need to combine these 2 codes and receive 1 working codes.

Comment: yeah but i got some errors :S

Comment: As how your queries are shown, without explaining what they do and what you expect, this will be hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an overall idea of joining both scripts into one from the below script. But you need to adjust/decide which column is required in the selection part as they are also need to add in the GROUP BY clause and the result will change-

```
SELECT `doc`.`date`,`doc`.`no`,`def`.`name`,`i`.`type`,
IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN  `d`.`type_group` = 'sales' THEN (`quantity` * `price` * `d`.`currency_value`) / 100 ELSE 0 END ), 0) AS `alacak` ,
IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN  `d`.`type_group` = 'purchases' THEN (`quantity` * `price` * `d`.`currency_value`) / 100 ELSE 0 END ) , 0) AS  `ödeme` ,

IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN  `d`.`type_group` = 'sales' THEN (`quantity` * `price` * `d`.`currency_value`) / 100 ELSE 0 END ), 0)
-
IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN  `d`.`type_group` = 'purchases' THEN (`quantity` * `price` * `d`.`currency_value`) / 100 ELSE 0 END ) , 0)
as `bakiye`
FROM `items` as `i`
RIGHT JOIN `documents` as `d` ON `d`.`id` = `i`.`document_id` 
RIGHT JOIN `definitions` as `def` ON `doc`.`type_id` = `def`.`id`
WHERE `d`.`id`= 2 
GROUP BY `d`.`date`,`d`.`no`,`def`.`name`,`i`.`type`
```

Comment: My inspiration is a up-vote and tick as answer from you ;) anyway, nice to hear that its helpful.